# Login Modal Yii

Tags: php, html, yii, yii2

I have a login page, but I need it to be via a modal. When I try to set the login code to the modal:

This is the login:

```
<section id="wrapper" class="login-register">
            <div class="login-box">
                <div class="white-box">

                    <img class="logo" src="<?= $url ?>assets/images/logo_redondo.png" alt="iniciar sesión" srcset="">
                    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                        'id' => 'login-form',
                        'layout' => 'horizontal',
                        'fieldConfig' => [
                            'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-12\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
                            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
                        ],
                    ]); ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['autofocus' => true])->label("Correo Electronico ") ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput()->label("Contraseña") ?>



                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 ">
                            <?= Html::submitButton('Iniciar Sesion', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 ">
                            <a style="width: 100%;" href="<?= $url ?>" class="btn btn-fill-out">Volver a la Pagina</a>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a style="width: 100%;" href="<?= Url::toRoute(['site/register']) ?>" class="btn btn-fill-out">Regístrarse</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>





                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }

    $model->password = '';
    return $this->renderPartial('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

and the model:

```
 <?php

 namespace app\models;

 use Yii;
 use yii\base\Model;

 /**
  * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
  *
  * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
  *
  */
 class LoginForm extends Model
 {
     public $email;
     public $password;
     public $rememberMe = true;

     private $_user = false;


/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // username and password are both required
        [['email', 'password'], 'required'],
        // rememberMe must be a boolean value
        ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        // password is validated by validatePassword()
        ['password', 'validatePassword'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Validates the password.
 * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
 *
 * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
 * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
 */
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
 * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
 */
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Finds user by [[username]]
 *
 * @return User|null
 */
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::findByEmail($this->email);
    }

         return $this->_user;
     }
 }
```

How can I place it on a modal? The idea is that when the user clicks on the user icon, the modal will run and show the same fields that he has in the login. I tried to place the login code inside the modal, but the page doesn't work.

Comment: Create Jquery function to handle click event on open login modal and make inside an ajax call to retrieve this form.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco how? sorry but, im new in Ajax and php :( Could you show me a way to do it?

Comment: Here is what you need: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/806/render-form-in-popup-via-ajax-create-and-update-with-ajax-validation-also-load-any-page-via-ajax-yii-2-0-2-3

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

`frontend/controllers/SiteController.php` file example with default login action:

```php
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        $model->password = '';

        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

public function actionLoginAjax()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            $model->password = '';

            return $this->renderAjax('_form_login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    return $this->redirect(['login']);
}
```

`frontend/views/login.php` file example:

```php
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model \common\models\LoginForm */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

$this->title = 'Login';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

$this->title                   = 'Contact';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

\yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
                                'id'     => 'modal-login',
                                'header' => '<h5 class="modal-title">Login</h5>',
                                'size'   => \yii\bootstrap\Modal::SIZE_LARGE,
                            ]);
\yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();
$js = <<<JS
$(function() {
   $('.send-login').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#modal-login').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
   });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
?>
<div class="site-login">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= Html::a('Login', [
        'site/login-ajax',
    ], ['class' => ' btn btn-success send-login']); ?>

    <p>Please fill out the following fields to login:</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox() ?>

                <div style="color:#999;margin:1em 0">
                    If you forgot your password you can <?= Html::a('reset it', ['site/request-password-reset']) ?>.
                    <br>
                    Need new verification email? <?= Html::a('Resend', ['site/resend-verification-email']) ?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`_form_login.php` file in the same directory `login.php` and example below.

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

/**
 * @var $this  \yii\web\View
 */
$js = <<<JS
$("document").ready(function(){
    //this will work with mulitpart data or regular form
    $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = document.getElementById('login-form');
        $.ajax({
              url: $(this).attr('action'),
              type: $(this).attr('method'),
              data: new FormData(form),
              mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
              contentType: false,
              cache: false,
              processData: false,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) {
                  //if there are serverside errors then ajax show them on the page
                  if (data.errors) {
                      $.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {
                          var el = $('#' + key);
                          el.parent('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                          el.next('.help-block').html(val);
                      });
                  } else {
                      //reload pjax and close boostrap modal
                      //$('#modal').modal('hide');
                  }
              }
        });
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
?>
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-create', 'enablePushState' => false]) ?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form', 'options' => ['data-pjax' => true]]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

`frontend/models/LoginForm.php` file without any changes:

```php
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * Login form
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user;


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     *
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        }
        
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    protected function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```